# python: unable to call sudo using Popen?

Tags: python, centos, nagios

Im trying to debug a nagios plugin (check_aacraid.py) that uses NRPE. The system in question is a new setup CentOS 6.2 fileserver.

The command that appears to be giving me trouble is:

```
for line in Popen(["/usr/bin/sudo", "/usr/bin/arcconf", "GETCONFIG", "1", "LD"],
                  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True).stdout:
```

If I run the script as the 'nagios' user it works fine. If it gets called from NRPE/XINETD it fails (NRPE reports "Unable to read output" - usu indicates an error).

I used strace to watch the output of xinetd and found this:

```
7706  execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["/usr/bin/sudo", "/usr/bin/arcconf", "GETCONFIG", "1", "AD"], [/* 15 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Im trying to figure out if its a problem with:
 -python
 -sudo
 -nagios
 -xinetd
 -other

I've trolled about for issues with sudo and have done the std things ( comment out 'requiretty', set path, add nagios user with 'NOPASSWD' ). Haven't found the problem yet.

Other commands run fine via NRPE ('check_user', etc).

Note: this is a published, established plugin for nagios. I've done something wrong on this system such that it isn't working.

Suggestions?

Answers to questions:
1) I can run the app if I login as 'nagios'.
2) Using 'visudo' I have this entry: 'nagios   ALL=(ALL)      NOPASSWD:ALL'
   - yes its a security hole. I will tighten it up when I get this thing working.
3) The permissions for /usr/bin/sudo are ---s--x--x. 2 root root 215144 May  9 23:59 /usr/bin/sudo

It appears that SELinux is the problem. When I 'echo 0 > /selinux/enforce' then the app runs properly. Now to figure out how to work with it instead of around it. @Josh - post this as an answer and I'll happily accept it!

Comment: Can you use sudo in the shell?

Comment: is the _nagios_ user allowed to run this command as root without password, there should be a rule in `/etc/sudoers` like `nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/arcconf` or similar... (or as which user is the script running?)

Comment: You're pretty clearly getting an *permission denied* error from the call to exec.  This means it's not a problem with Python, or Nagios, or Xinetd.  It does suggest that the permissions on `sudo` may be incorrect.  What does `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` show?

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?  If executing sudo from xinetd gets a permission denied error and executing it outside of xinetd is succeeding, then it seems that something like SELinux might be enforcing a policy denying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like SELinux is the problem. If executing sudo from xinetd gets a permission denied error and executing it outside of xinetd is succeeding, then it seems that something like SELinux might be enforcing a policy that denies it.